Defining PCF8574 I2C extender devices in a C++ class
I am trying to use ESP32 with PCF8574, using VS Code and PlatformIO.
Basically, it is working well, I can upload code after compilation and control the leds.
While defining the I2C extender (PCF8574), the physical I2C address is required. In this case it is 0x38, and it is working well from hardware point of view, as long as I use it directly from the setup() routine.
The definition looks like this: PCF8574 i2c_ctrl1(0x38); // Option A
When placed within an init() routine (see the code below, as "Option A"), the init() works well, but of course the i2c_ctrl variable is not recognized outside the init() function.
I was sure that option B (defining the i2c_ctrl variable in the global part of the class will work, yet in this case the compilation failed because of the 0x38 value with the error:

error: expected identifier before numeric constant

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:
#include "PCF8574.h"

class I2C_devices{
    
    public:
        PCF8574 i2c_ctrl(0x38);  // Option B
    
    void I2C_init() {
        //PCF8574 i2c_ctrl(0x38); // Option A
        i2c_ctrl.pinMode(P3,OUTPUT); // LED1
        i2c_ctrl.pinMode(P4,OUTPUT); // LED2
        i2c_ctrl.pinMode(P5,OUTPUT); // LED3
        i2c_ctrl.pinMode(P6,OUTPUT); // LED4
        i2c_ctrl.pinMode(P7,OUTPUT); // LED5
        i2c_ctrl.begin();
    } // of I2C_init

    void Led1_On() {
        i2c_ctrl.digitalWrite(P3,LOW);
    } // of Led1_On()

    void Led2_On() {
        i2c_ctrl.digitalWrite(P4,LOW);
    } // of Led2_On()
}

I was expecting the global variable to work, especially because it requires the physical address, since there might be other such extenders.

Your global variable needs a name (you now have a type and a constructor, but not a name for your variable).

Isn't i2c_ctrl the name? Because it was working as option A (defined in the i2c_init procedure).

you're right, I'm guessing the error comes from the "class" line: examples like this one use a global variable: https://github.com/RobTillaart/PCF8574/blob/master/examples/PCF8574_test/PCF8574_test.ino
But your code has a definition of a public member of the class. You should call the constructor not in that location, but in the constructor of your I2C_devices class.

This is my I2C class (somehow the top 2 lines of the class definition are visible outside the code section).

Here the help I got elsewhere:
The below code style solved the problem, by using constructor.
#include "PCF8574.h"

class Extension : public PCF8574 {
  public:
    Extension(const byte addr = 0x38) : PCF8574(addr) {}
    
    void begin() {
      pinMode(P3, OUTPUT); // LED1
      pinMode(P4, OUTPUT); // LED2
      pinMode(P5, OUTPUT); // LED3
      pinMode(P6, OUTPUT); // LED4
      pinMode(P7, OUTPUT); // LED5
    }

    void led1On() { digitalWrite(P3, LOW); }
    void led2On() { digitalWrite(P4, LOW); }
};

// Create an instance of Extension with the default address 0x38
Extension extender;

